# Find friends using an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebooker

How to programmatically find which of my friends are using my application using Mogli or Facebooker2.

If the only way is to use FQL can someone provide an example?

I think the code bellow is able to find the

```
select uid, name, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and is_app_user=1
```

Comment: This is something the facebook-graphy-api should provide. I don't think you need to do it yourself.

Comment: Can you provide links to the API and show us any information you are storing in your db?

Comment: But the problem is that graph api is not providing that.

Comment: on a side note, I absolutely LOVE the title of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+uid%2C+name%2C+is_app_user+from+user+where+uid+in+%28select+uid2+from+friend+where+uid1%3Dme%28%29%29+and+is_app_user%3D1%0A
&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
&format=json
```

And is returning the correct results so FQL is actually working!